# Add (and calculate) rows to dataframe until condition is met:

Tags: python, loops, numpy, pandas, while-loop

I'm attempting to build a dataframe that adds 1 to the prior row in a column until a condition is met. In this case, I want to continue to add rows until column 'AGE' = 100.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


RP = {'AGE' : pd.Series([10]), 
      'SI' : pd.Series([60])}

RPdata = pd.DataFrame(RP)


i = RPdata.tail(1)['AGE']

RPdata2 = pd.DataFrame()

while [i < 100]:
    RPdata2['AGE'] = i + 1

    RPdata2['SI'] = RPdata.tail(1)['SI']    

    RPdata = pd.concat([RPdata, RPdata2], axis = 0)
    break

print RPdata
```

Results

```
    Age    SI
0   10     60
0   11     60
```

I understand that the break statement prevents multiple iterations, but the loop appears to be infinite without it.

I'm attempting to achieve:

```
    Age    SI
0   10     60
0   11     60
0   12     60
0   13     60
0   14     60
.   .      60
0  100     60
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with a while loop? Should I pursue a for loop solution instead?

Answer (score 0):

There may be other problems, but you're going to get in an infinite loop with `while [i < 100]:` since a non-empty list will always evaluate to True. Change that to `while (i < 100):` (parens optional) and remove your `break` statement, which is forcing just one iteration.

Comment: Thanks Randy C. I gave it a try, yielding.. ValueError: The truth value of a series is ambiguous, Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any(), or a.all(). I added the [] to avoid this. I tried ([i < 100]) as well, with no luck. (Just an infinite loop, as you suggested).

Comment: `i = RPdata.tail(1)['AGE']` is initializing i to be a pd.Series with one value in it. You can do `i = RPdata['AGE'].iloc[-1]` to just get the value 10 instead.

Comment: I apologize I don't know how to properly format the printing results in the comments section. Age does not read as 11 as it should, however i is = to 10.